# I don't know how to read volume from multiple oscillators and connect it to a visualizer

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

Finally I realized after analyzing my code several times that the problem was with the information given by the command "analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData (dataArray);".

This information ignores the oscillator volume previously set by "volume.gain.value = 0.01;".
`

```
function startTime() {
    const today = new Date();
    let h = today.getHours();
    let m = today.getMinutes();
    let s = today.getSeconds();
    let ms = today.getMilliseconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
    return ms;
  }
  
  function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
  }

  function sleep(milliseconds) {
    const date = Date.now();
    let currentDate = null;
    do {
      currentDate = Date.now();
    } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);



  }





  var ctxClass = window.audioContext || window.AudioContext || window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext
  // We instance the class, create the context
  var ctx = new ctxClass();
  var analyser = ctx.createAnalyser();

//audioSource = context.createMediaElementSource();
//analyser =  context.createAnalyser();
//audioSource.connect(analyser);
//analyser.connect(context.destination);    

analyser.fftSize = 8192;
var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount; 
var dataArray = new Float32Array(bufferLength);
var c = document.getElementById("oscilloscope");
var canvas = c.getContext("2d");
var WIDTH = 1000;
var HEIGHT = 1000;



function draw() {
    drawVisual = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData(dataArray);
    canvas.fillStyle = 'rgb(200, 200, 200)';
    canvas.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    canvas.lineWidth = 2;
    canvas.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';

    canvas.beginPath();
    var sliceWidth = WIDTH * 1.0 / bufferLength;
      var x = 0;
      for(var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
   
        var v = dataArray[i] * 200.0;
        var y =  HEIGHT/2+v;

        if(i === 0) {
          canvas.moveTo(x, y);
        } else {
          canvas.lineTo(x, y);
        }

        x += sliceWidth;
 
      };
      canvas.lineTo(c.width, c.height/2);
      canvas.stroke();
};
draw();


function funkcja()
{

    // Create the oscillator
    var osc = ctx.createOscillator();
    // Define type of wave
    osc.type = 'sine';
    // We create a gain intermediary
    var volume = ctx.createGain();
    // We connect the oscillator with the gain knob
    osc.connect(volume);
    // Then connect the volume to the context destination
    volume.connect(ctx.destination);
    // We can set & modify the gain knob
    volume.gain.value = 0.01;

    osc.connect(analyser);
    
    //We can test it with some frequency at current time
    osc.frequency.setValueAtTime(400.0, ctx.currentTime);
    if (osc.noteOn) osc.noteOn(0);
    if (osc.start) osc.start();



   

    // We'll have to stop it at some point
    // setTimeout(function () {
    //     if (osc.noteOff) osc.noteOff(0);
    //     if (osc.stop) osc.stop();
    //     // We can insert a callback here, let them know you've finished, may be play next note?
    //     //finishedCallback();
    // }, 5000);

// let ms;
// let o2 = ctx.createOscillator();
// const  g2 = ctx.createGain();

// o2.connect(analyser);
// o2.connect(g2);
// o2.type = 'sine';
// g2.gain.value = 0.01;
// g2.connect(ctx.destination);

// o2.start();
//    setInterval(() => {
//      console.log('Hello world');
//      ms = startTime();
//      let frequency2 = 200.0; // +ms%500
//      o2.frequency.setValueAtTime(frequency2, ctx.currentTime);
    
//    }, 1);

}
```

`

I couldn't find an answer to my problem anywhere, although I thought I would do something about it quickly.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).